# How Rails Controllers Should be Created? Should it be a verb, noun or an adjective?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I need some advice, what is the rule of the thumb when creating Rails controllers names?

Should controller be all be verbs or a combination of nouns and verbs (or adjectives)?

This is the example provided on creating controllers in Rails,

./script/generate controller CreditCard open debit credit close # which is a combination of nouns and verbs (unless credit and debit is made into a verb)

However, if I create a scaffold, the default controller actions would be index, show, new, edit, update, destroy, which has 1 noun and all verb.

Should nouns and verbs be separated completely for sake of consistency also providing a clearer project goals? Or should I mix them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller names should be plural nouns; controller actions should be verbs.

For example, to generate `CreditCardsController` with the actions `open` and `close`, you would use `./script/generate controller CreditCards open close`.

- The first argument, `controller`, tells what to generate.
- The second argument, `CreditCards`, names the controller; plural nouns only.
- The remaining arguments, `open close`, name the controller actions; verbs only.

If you use `script/generate` without naming any actions, the generator assumes the seven RESTful defaults, as you mentioned: `index show new create edit update destroy`. All of these are, or can be, verbs.